# Monitoring network connection of Windows Server in real-time

Tags: windows-server-2003, monitoring, network-monitoring

I'm looking for a way to monitor the network connection from my PC to a Windows Server running on our network. My PC is running Windows 7 and the server is running Windows Server 2003 R2. I'm looking for things like dropped packets, errors, packet loss, data loss, loss of connection, etc.

If it helps the server is a VM running on XenServer 5.5 - if I'm able to monitor it using XS instead?

Does anyone know the best way to do this for free?

Comment: You'll get better answers if you describe what problem you're trying to solve, or are just doing this as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use your network switch to monitor the port the Windows 7 PC is using.  It will have all of these statistics (in real time).

Comment: Cool. Unfortunately I'm not sure which port I'm connected to. :(

Comment: @Reado - Can you find out? If you're just a user, and not an admin, on this network, you really should work with your local tech support and admins to help you.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for the idea of looking at the switch port.

Ping server four times if it doesn't reply send an email.

Set it run as cron job every 5 minutes.

```
check=$(ping -c $count $server | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }')
if [ $check -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Host : $server is down (ping failed) at $(date)" | mail -s "$subject" $email
fi
```

I got it from [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/simple-linux-and-unix-system-monitoring-with-ping-command-and-scripts.html) which is a complete script.

Comment: If I ran a ping from a Linux server with a timeout of 0ms, that would hammer the server with pings, but would this be recommended or not? Could I use SNMP or is that something else?

Comment: You could use ping -c and a cron job. Or snmp. It's all about polling.